# Is there a framework such as Loopback or Sails.js for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sails.js, asp.net-core, loopbackjs

It looks like the NodeJs community built multiple framework to allow quick prototyping of Web Service and API. However, I can't find the same thing for ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core.

Is there a framework such as Loopback or SailJs for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Web API + Swashbuckle is the closest comparison in the .NET world.

[ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is a framework for building web APIs on top of the .NET Framework.

[Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) is an implementation of Swagger documentation generation for Web API.

If Azure is an option then both [Azure Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/app-service/mobile/) and [Azure API Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform/) provide some additional level of abstraction from datasources, authentication and documentation.